# Should game objects draw themselves?

Tags: java, 2d, rendering, design-patterns, mvc

Assuming you have classes like `Player`, `Enemy`, `Map` and `Tile`.

The first approach to structuring rendering code would be to give each a `render()` method and let it draw itself:

```
void render(){
   player.draw();
   enemy.draw();
   // etc.
}
```

But considering the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) perspective, that feels wrong... Another idea would be to make a `Renderer` class, but then I wonder how you give the `Renderer` information what to draw.

Which one should I choose and why?

Comment: Doesn't feel right? Explain further.

Comment: I just think that game logic and  visual representation should be seperated, that's why it doesn't feel right.

Comment: But they *are* separated. You have a `player.draw()` separately from `player.update()`, right?

Comment: I have a ``render()`` and a ``update()`` method in my game loop.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, my question wasn't if a game object should draw itself, it was, how to approach rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's boil this down to dependencies.

Now the first thing is first, *how* do you render something? Well the logical manner tells us that we need *some* asset which will be loaded and then displayed.

Assets:

- Sprite
- Sound
- Music

Now how to you get these assets into your program? You typically will have some sort of *Asset Manager* who's responsibility is to load them for you. Now you have a bunch of Sprites/Sounds/etc... who are owned by *who*?

Well the player is made up of several assets, and these assets are used exclusively by the player. It then makes sense to have the player directly manage its own assets. So you might have:

```
class Player
{
    Sprite _playerMain;
    Sprite _playerSword;
    Sound _aughghghghgh;
};
```

Now how do you draw these? You've already mentioned two possible approaches, both are good approaches.

**Let the player draw itself:** Each object in the game will have a `Draw();` function, and would call `Draw();` on each Sprite object it owns.

Pros:

- Used by half-life 2 and several other games
- Very simple to implement
- Fine control over render order

Cons:

- Plenty of duplicate code
- Unable to take advantage of batching or other rendering tricks
- Must pre-sort your sprite layers

**Use a rendering manager:** A rendering manager will typically have a render priority (layers), with each object assigned to a given layer. The manager then batches and renders sprites from layer to layer. Your sprites will essentially add/remove them to/from the rendering manager.

Pros:

- Separation of data and logic
- Sprite layering is built-in, no need to pre-sort
- Able to batch sprites efficiently
- Player, Enemy, and other objects no longer need to encapsulate rendering code

Cons:

- Additional infrastructure to write

Now each approach is just fine. My current project is almost a hybrid of the two due to special requirements. Now you aren't going to be writing a AAA game, so work with whichever approach you prefer.

Comment: Is it good design to take the Sprite into the ``Player`` class? Shouldn't the ``Player`` class just contain data like e.g. HP, Strength, etc.?

Comment: Your player should contain every bit of data that it needs to function. If the player uses a sprite to make itself visible, then it should own that sprite.

Comment: @user42030 I agree, the `Player` class shouldn't need to know anything about its sprite(s) which are observing the player object and could be drawing it in potentially multiple different views in many different ways (minimap for example).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea if you are talking about 3D / GPU rendering.

It's fine if you're rendering 2D / non-GPU, as it may make more sense to you organisationally.

The reason is that GPU rendering, for optimal (or even reasonable) performance, requires individual render *passes* that render groups of game objects with similar properties i.e. materials, since each material uses different shaders and sometimes, different textures... switching between different textures and shaders can cost considerable time on the GPU, hence this is best avoided.

Allowing each object to render itself (rather than being observed and rendered *by* a single monolithic renderer) breaks this grouping which would allow the GPU to perform optimally. Some game objects can consist of multiple different materials, which would also break this grouping.

Even so, for small numbers of objects and low-cost shaders, this doesn't really matter much running on modern GPUs. But as soon as you have complex materials and many game objects, it is a far better idea to render from a single class / function, by inspecting game object properties.